# What does it mean by "delegate" key word in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a photo using my Hololens and I am referring to Unity manual in C#.

In the manual, I found the following code snippet including the keyword "delegate". I know that  "delegate" keyword is used to referring to a function. But in this code example, I can not understand how does it work accordingly.

What is the exact purpose of  "delegate" keyword in this function

```
PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, delegate (PhotoCapture captureObject)
{
    photoCaptureObject = captureObject;
    CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters();
    cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
    cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
    cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = 
    cameraResolution.height;
    cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PhotoCapture.CreateAsync method signature will probably look like this:

```
PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(bool b, Action<PhotoCapture> action){
   ...
}
```

Which means you will not be passing a normal object, but a reference to a function which can (but not has to) be executed.

The call can also be written by using a lambda expxression instead of the 'delegate' keyword, like this:

```
PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, captureObject =>
     {
         photoCaptureObject = captureObject;
         CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters();
         cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
         cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
         cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = 
         cameraResolution.height;
         cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

     });
```